# (Appcelerator Titanium) How to search for all files on smart phone's memories with given file name and display them in an OptionDialog?

Tags: memory, full-text-search, titanium, appcelerator

I've already searched for similar questions, but I've only found some ones that point to this link:
[http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160170/android---how-to-search-for-all-files-on-sd-card-with-given-file-extensions-and-display-them-in-an-optiondialog][1], that is not very clear and has not an explained code script example.

I'm asking for *A CODE EXAMPLE* that permits me to search a specific file name in ALL smart phone's memories (internal memory and SD card, if present).
Then display all the found items on a OptionDialog.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I think the answer in the given link is ok so far. You use Titanium to open the different storages and iterate over the directories and all sub levels. You should try that yourself and ask again if you have specific question. StackOverflow is no "We do others work completely" website.

Comment: Hi Robin, I'm a beginner in Appcelerator programming and for this reason I inserted this question.
Anyway I'm not asking to do a completely work for me, but only to give me "a code example" that permits me to complete the work by myself. That is different.
Thanks for your time answering me